# Mongoose: how to redefine a schema programatically?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have many separate Mongoose schemas referencing one another with `ObjecId`s.
Based on those, now I want to compose an another one, programatically.

I've tried something like the following:

```
const Offers = require('../offers/offersModel')
const Stores = require('../stores/storesModel')

const flattenedStores = Stores.schema
const flattenedOffers = Offers.schema

// this step is not working as I expected
flattenedOffers.paths.storeId = flattenedStores 

const FeedsSchema = new Schema({ 
    offerId: flattenedOffers,
    // ...other fields
})
```

Originally, in Offers model, storeId is an ObjectId referencing Stores model:

```
OffersSchema = new Schema({
    storeId : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Stores',
        required: true
    },
    // ...other fields
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Offers', OffersSchema)
```

I wanted to programatically change it to a sub flattenedStores schema. But it didn't work. How to do that?

This example is simple and I could indeed just insert the whole schema manually inside FeedsSchema. However, in my real use case, there's a long chain of schemas, with many fields each, where only a single field is a reference to another schema.

I would rather redefine just those single references instead of injecting the whole structure by hand into FeedsSchema... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found a way around... separating the schema object fields from the constructed Schema:

```
const OffersSchemaObj = {
    storeId : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Stores',
        required: true
    },
    // ...other fields
}
OffersSchema = new Schema(OffersSchemaObj)
exports.model = mongoose.model('Offers', OffersSchema)
exports.schema = OffersSchemaObj
```

Then I can use the schema object and change whatever I want:

```
const OffersSchema = require('../offers/offersModel').schema
const StoresSchema = require('../stores/storesModel').schema

OffersSchema.storeId = StoresSchema

const FeedsSchema = new Schema({ 
    offerId: OffersSchema,
    // ...other fields
})
```